# CakePHP ORM :: Disconnect database

Tags: php, cakephp, orm

I'm using the CakePHP ORM package inside a Gearman Worker.
Package : https://packagist.org/packages/cakephp/orm

```
$connectionObject = ConnectionManager::get('Backend');
$usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users', ['connection' => $connectionObject]);
$countActiveUsers = $usersTable->find()->where(['active' => 1])->count();
```

I'm trying to find a way to disconnect the database when a job finish to be processed because now, even if there is no job in the queue, the connection between the worker and the database remains open.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the issue with the connection remaining open, why is it that you have to manually close the connection? Could it be that the connection is reused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `disconnect()` on the Connection object.

```
$connectionObject->disconnect();
```

See: http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.Database.Connection.html#190-198

Comment: I noticed this in the documentation but how to access to the object instance ?

Comment: It's `$connectionObject` in your code. The ConnectionManager returns a Connection object.

Comment: Thanks seems to work but still, if I restart my PostgreSQL while my worker is running, I got an error 
     `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 no connection to the server`

So I still need to restart the worker and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Since the worker is always running and the DB server could go down, I would suggest catching the exception when it tries to connect, and try reconnecting a little bit later.

Comment: The thing is that even if I try to reconnect later, I still get the error.
To fix it, I need to kill and restart my all workers and its painful because I have 39 workers.